ffmpeg replaygain dsf to wav not working when value is +
I use replaygain to ensure that the volume level when streaming to my receiver is more or less equal. It works fine for flac, mp3, m4a or aiff files but not for dsf files.
When I convert a file where the replaygain has a negative value (-6.0 dB), it works, however for files with a positive value (+6 dB) it fails or does nothing with the values.
I'm using the following command /arguments:
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel verbose -i "inputs.dsf" -af volume=replaygain=track:replaygain_noclip=0 -ar 176000 "output.wav"

Is this by design or do I have to correct my command line?
